# Sizing specific region on map to defined map width

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

Am trying to size a mapbox map of the continental US to a 600px wide window. Zoom level 4 is ideal, but that cuts off sides of the map. Zoom 3 makes the map too small. [Here is current zoom 3 view - too much white space.](http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/mapbox/debtmap_600px.html)

How can I fill in my map window with the mapbox tile? I've tried re-exporting from Tilemill with wider bounds to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the south-west and the north-east points on your map and than make them fit within the bounds of the view. Something like this:

```
var southWest = L.latLng(40.712, -74.227),
    northEast = L.latLng(40.774, -74.125);
map.fitBounds([
    southWest,
    northEast
]);
```

You can see on this [link](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/fit-map-to-markers/) how fitBounds method works in leaflet (mapbox).

Comment: That won't work because when the fitBounds method calculates the zoomlevel it uses to call the setView method, it will come up with an integer because setView only accepts integers. In this case fitBounds will give zoomfactor three, which he/she already said he tried and finds too small.